# 2 Dropdownlists with values from database, need to hide selected value from first in the second dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page with 2 dropdownlists, both have same values bind from sql
When i select 1 value in box 1 that should not be "active" in box2

APSX

```
</head>
```

```
    </div>

    <div id="div2">

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

    </div>

</form>
```

CS file

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FillQualCheckBoxList();

        }

    }

    private void FillQualCheckBoxList()
    {
        string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CashGameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str);
        string query = "SELECT * FROM tblStoPokerGames Where ACTIVE = '1'";

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        adp.Fill(dt);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Games";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Selected";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));
        DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Games";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Selected";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));

    }
```

}
}

I have tried a lot of stuff but now i have removed all that wasn't working.
I have tried autopostback on the dropdownlist
Several scripts

I think i need to to databinding for second dropdownlist but i dont know how

Cheers
Ace

This is the code i am trying now:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="padding:45px">

        <h2>Please select two city destinations for your trip</h2>

        <div style="float:left" >
            <h4>First City choice</h4>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                AutoPostBack="true"
                DataValueField="Selected"
                DataTextField="Games"
                Height="24px" Width="149px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
            <h4>Second City choice</h4>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                DataValueField="Selected"
                DataTextField="Games"
                Height="24px" Width="149px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Code behind

```
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FillQualCheckBoxList();
        }
    }


    private void FillQualCheckBoxList()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM tblStoPokerGames Where ACTIVE = '1'";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = MyRst(query);

        DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));

    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text != "Please select")
        {
            // clear and re-load 2nd cbo ALWAYS, but skip current selection

            DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));

            foreach (ListItem OneRow in DropDownList1.Items)
            {
                if (OneRow.Value != DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
                {
                    DropDownList2.Items.Add(OneRow);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CashGameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        var rst = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                // fill items table
                rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rst;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean with _should not be "active"_ a) Visible but not selectable, b) not visible at all ?

Comment: "not selectable" or "not visible" doesnt matter for me, just so you cant select same again

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can adopt a few tricks to save a BOATLOAD of code!

The first problem? What happens if the user selects the 2nd combo first?

or worse, they select first, then 2nd, and THEN go back to the first cbo and select the same city as the 2nd? You can try and "dance" around this, but a really simple approach?

IN EVERY case that you select the first cbo, you clear and re-load 2nd combo box with every row except the selected on in the first.

This solves a boatload of code issues, but ALSO solves a boatload of UI issues. So, if you re-select the first one, then the 2nd combo go back to please select - really minor issue - and probably even better then trying to deal with the user then goes back to first combo, and selects the same city as the already selected one in the 2nd city. (in fact, I doubt users would do that "much" but, they could, and the above simple idea fixes this.

So, ok, here is our markup :

```
       <h2>Please select two city destinations for your trip</h2>

        <div style="float:left" >
            <h4>First City choice</h4>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity1" runat="server" 
                AutoPostBack="true"
                DataValueField="ID"
                DataTextField="City"  Height="24px" Width="149px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCity1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
            <h4>Second City choice</h4>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity2" runat="server" 
                DataValueField="ID"
                DataTextField="City"  Height="24px" Width="149px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

And our code is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           LoadCbo();
        }
    }

    void LoadCbo()
    {
        DataTable rstData = MyRst("SELECT ID, City FROM City ORDER BY City");
        cboCity1.DataSource = rstData;
        cboCity1.DataBind();
        cboCity1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));
    }

    protected void cboCity1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboCity1.SelectedItem.Text != "Please select")
        {
            // clear and re-load 2nd cbo ALWAYS, but skip current selection

            cboCity2.Items.Clear();
            cboCity2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));

            foreach (ListItem OneRow in cboCity1.Items)
            {
                if (OneRow.Value != cboCity1.SelectedValue)
                {
                    cboCity2.Items.Add(OneRow);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
       string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CashGameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        var rst = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                // fill items table
                rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rst;
    }
```

And now how have this:

[image]

Note how we not even give or let the user selected the 2nd cbo as of yet.

If they select a value, say like this:

[image]

Then with auto-post back, our simple code of this runs:

```
   protected void cboCity1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboCity1.SelectedItem.Text != "Please select")
        {
            // clear and re-load 2nd cbo ALWAYS, but skip current selection

            cboCity2.Items.Clear();
            cboCity2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));

            foreach (ListItem OneRow in cboCity1.Items)
            {
                if (OneRow.Value != cboCity1.SelectedValue)
                {
                    cboCity2.Items.Add(OneRow);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And now we get this:

[image]

You can see our first entry is not in the list.

And if we re-select the first cbo, then the 2nd one is cleared, and we don't have any fancy code to deal with the user changing there mind.

## Edit

So, your markup will have the two drop downs.

and your code thus will look similar to this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        FillQualCheckBoxList();
    }
}


private void FillQualCheckBoxList()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tblStoPokerGames Where ACTIVE = '1'";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = MyRst(query);

    DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));

}

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text != "Please select")
        {
            // clear and re-load 2nd cbo ALWAYS, but skip current selection

            DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));

            foreach (ListItem OneRow in DropDownList1.Items)
            {
                if (OneRow.Value != DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
                {
                    DropDownList2.Items.Add(OneRow);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
       string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CashGameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        var rst = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                // fill items table
                rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rst;
    }
```

So note how we don't fill the 2nd cbo box, since we force and start out with the user MUST select the first combo box (DropDownlist1).

The markup I had for this is this:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="padding:45px">

            <h2>Please select two city destinations for your trip</h2>

            <div style="float:left" >
                <h4>First City choice</h4>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    DataValueField="Selected"
                    DataTextField="Games"
                    Height="24px" Width="149px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCity1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>

            <div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
                <h4>Second City choice</h4>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity2" runat="server" 
                    DataValueField="Selected"
                    DataTextField="Games"
                    Height="24px" Width="149px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Note how I put the data text and data value settings in the markup - it cleans up the code behind.

NOTE VERY careful how the 2nd combo box DOES NOT have a auto post back - it does not need one.

Also, you have it is a assume your sql table has two columns, Selected, and Games - correct?

Comment: When i select the first box it gets cleared right away, so it goes back to "Please select"
Then i dont understand what this does
public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        var rst = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                // fill items table
                rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rst;
    }

Comment: the MyRst does the same thing as your existing code you had to get the data with sql. It just nicer to read, easer to read, and allows you to move the code that pulls data into a datatable with great ease, and then shove into a dropdown list. I'll edit it to use your connection string.

Comment: See my edit, and see my sample code edit - I have added some "air code" which should work, or be VERY close to what you need here.

Comment: When i select a game in the first dropdown it flashes and then shows please select again
It never gets selected

Comment: You have to post your code and how it works. It is 100%, and in fact 200% VERY imporant to place the first load of the comb box in the if (!IsPostBack) code stub. In fact, quite much any and all pages that load up grids, dropdown list, or any kind of data loading in a page WILL NOT WORK UNLESS you use the if (!IsPostBack) code block in your page load event. Failure to do this, will render quite much ANY AND ALL pages of no use or even able to function correctly with any post-backs.

Comment: Looking at your orginal code, you DO HAVE that all imporant if (!IsPostBack), so that looks good. Remember, only the first cbo needs and has a post back (auto postback  = true), there is in fact no code required for the 2nd cbo box - in fact we don't even fill it with any data, since our first cbo box upon user selection automatic fills out the 2nd cob for use with the same data - minus the one row that is selected - we skip that row.